# Unable to initialize default values when using ngDefaultControl in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-ngmodel

I use a child component, the child component contains the ngDefaultControl property.

el-input.component.ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'el-input',
  template: ` <input type="text" /> `,
})
export class ElInput {}
```

I use it like this：

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
    <el-input ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="name"></el-input>
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
    <button (click)="onClick()">Change Name</button>
  `,
})
export class HomeComponent {
  name: string = 'Tom';

  onClick() {
    this.name = 'Jack';
  }
}
```

I set the initial value of name to Tom, but el-input doesn't show it. And I click the button and nothing happens
[image]

after clicked the button:

[image]

how should i fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [(ngModel)] is an angular directive for native html element

If you want to create a custom input, you need to create an @Input variable inside your el element inside the elElement component and bind it inside your app

```
@Component({
selector: 'el-input',
template: ` <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='name' /> `,
})
export class ElInput {
   @Input()
   name: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
    <el-input ngDefaultControl [name]="name"></el-input>
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
    <button (click)="onClick()">Change Name</button>
  `,
})
export class HomeComponent {
  name: string = 'Tom';

  onClick() {
    this.name = 'Jack';
  }
}
```

and if you want to change the value of the variable name inside your app-home when the el input is updated, you need to create an @Output variable which will emit the new value for your app-home component

I made a stackblitz which solve your problem here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utyrxo